# How to create a for loop for combining several data frames and df subsets into one data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

I'm trying to modify data frames and struggle with combining my operations into a for loop. I want to subset a data frame according to one particular column, attach different rows to each subset and combine the modified subsets into one single data frame again. Let's use the iris data as an example:

```
#Create data frame subsets based on Species column
iris_subs <- split(iris, iris$Species)

#create an empty data frame with the same columns as in iris and one empty row
emptydf <- iris[FALSE,]
emptydf[nrow(emptydf)+1,] <- NA

#create a data frame with sums for each species
iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarise_all(sum) -> iris_sums
iris_sums <- iris_sums[,-c(1)] #delete column with species names

#Combine data frames into one data frame with original data, sum for this species and an empty row for each subset
iris_setosa <- bind_rows(iris_subs[1], iris_sums[1,], emptydf)
iris_versicolor <- bind_rows(iris_subs[2], iris_sums[2,], emptydf)
iris_virginica <- bind_rows(iris_subs[3], iris_sums[3,], emptydf)
new_iris <- bind_rows(iris_setosa, iris_versicolor, iris_virginica)
```

This code does the job. However, I have a couple of hundreds of data frames which I want to process in this way and the number of different species varies for each data frame. How can I automate the last part in a for loop?

I would like something like this

```
#empty data frame to store output
new_iris <- iris[FALSE,]    

for (i in iris_subs) {
        new_iris[i] <- bind_rows(iris_subs[i], iris_sums[i,], emptydf)
        new_iris <- merge(new_iris[i])
    }

Error in iris_subs[i] : invalid subscript type 'list'
```

Apart from the error, this is probably way too simple... I'm an R beginner and have searched the net for days now, but cannot find any answer to this. Does anyone have a suggestion for how to achieve this? Thank you for any hints!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a function that will sum up all numeric columns of a data.frame, and leave other columns as NA, append this to original data frame:

```
numericCols = sapply(iris,is.numeric)

func = function(df,numCols){

iris_sums <- colSums(df[,numCols])
result <- rep(NA,ncol(df))
names(result) <- colnames(df)
result[names(iris_sums)] <- iris_sums
rbind(df,result,rep(NA,ncol(df)))
}
```

Then we use purrr to map each subset:

```
split(iris,iris$Species) %>% map_dfr(func,numCols=numericCols)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This looks nice, but I lack the empty row in between the the sums and the next species. Do you know how to include it?

Comment: oh you need that. Ok sure of course. I thought it was not intended

Comment: This looks great! Thank you so much for your help! :)

Answer (score 2):

We can create a function and repeat it for all the dataframes. Here is a shorter version of what you were trying to do

```
library(dplyr)

repeat_process <- function(df) {
   iris_sums <- df %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarise_all(sum) %>% select(-Species)
   df %>% bind_rows(iris_sums, emptydf[rep(1:nrow(emptydf), n_distinct(df$Species)), ])
}
```

Now let's assume you have a list of dataframes

```
list_df <- list(iris, iris)
```

You can apply this function to each dataframe in the list

```
lapply(list_df, repeat_process)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However, this appends the sums and the empty rows at the end of the final data frame, not after each species subset. Do you know how to fix this issue?